# I can't see a cropper in IE7/8. No problem in FF and the demo (with IE7/8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

i have this [cropper](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs1/web/frontend.php/miembros/cambiarAvatarOK/id/1) in my app.

> login: fer
>   password: m

*Note: after loginning you will be redirected to another page. Then click again the
link i mention.*

I can see it working in FF, **but not in IE7/8** (Windows XP SP2, just installed).

It's supposed it works ok, because I don't have any problems to operate the [demo](http://www.defusion.org.uk/demos/060519/cropper.php) in both browsers, and in IE 8 Developer Tools the all the .js's necessary appeared as loaded.

I have contacted with the developer of the cropper but he didn't reply.

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: Thanks Beska, but if the answer was not usefull for me, do you think should i accepted it (i understand as "Accept" giving to the response a green tick) ???

Comment: @user248959: Nope.  You're exactly right...non-useful responses defintitely shouldn't be upvoted or marked as accepted.  However, a 9% rating will always be looked at with a jaundiced eye...people won't bother going through all of your questions to determine if this is justified.  (I see you've improved it to 24%, though that will still be considered low, by many people).  Sadly, if the answers you've recieved aren't of good quality, I don't have a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove the **comma** at **line 61** in your source code? IE is very annoid with errornous commas.

```
function() {
    new Cropper.Img (
        't3soeta',
        {
            minWidth: 200,
            minHeight: 100,
            ratioDim: { x: 200, y: 100 },
            displayOnInit: true,
            onEndCrop: saveCoords,
            onloadCoords: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 200, y2: 100 }, <---
        }
    ) <---
}
```

I'm not sure, since Javascript doesn't require semi-colons everywhere, but I would personally have put a semi-colon to end the `new` statement.

Does this help?

Comment: @user248959: Try to correct the error in the version referenced by your link. Then I might be able to get closer to the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. It works fine now on IE7/8.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<script src="scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/cropper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">';

    Event.observe (
    window,
    'load',
    function() {
        new Cropper.ImgWithPreview(
            't3soeta',
            {
                minWidth: 300,
                minHeight: 200,
                ratioDim: { x: 300, y: 200 },
                displayOnInit: true,
                onEndCrop: saveCoords,
                onloadCoords: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 300, y2: 200 },
                previewWrap: 'preview'
            }
        )
    }
);

function saveCoords (coords, dimensions)
{
    $( 'x1' ).value = coords.x1;
    $( 'y1' ).value = coords.y1;
    $( 'width' ).value = dimensions.width;
    $( 'height' ).value = dimensions.height;
}
</script>
```